# $date not picking up current date - Sitecore

Tags: datetime, sitecore

I am having an issue while setting default value for datetime field in sitecore standard values. 
I know that $date takes the current date. If I specify $date in standard values for a date time field , it always takes the date as "1/1/0001".

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to enter tokens in the fields on the standard values, and then these will be replaced with other values, but **only when a new item which use that template is created**. It will not set date for the existing items which use this template.

**$date** is one of the token and it's replates with the system date (***yyyyMMdd***).

There is a blog post written by John West which explains how to [Expand Standard Values Tokens in Existing Items with the Sitecore ASP.NET CMS](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/expand-standard-values-tokens-in-existing-items-with-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms).

---

**EDIT:**

Here is the code which is a part of `MasterVariablesReplacer` class which is used to replace **$date** token:

```cs
text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$date", (Func<string>) (() => DateUtil.IsoNowDate), context);
```

It is called from the `ReplaceVariables` processor, which is a part of `expandInitialFieldValue` pipeline (see `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` for all the `expandInitialFieldValue` processors).

You can try to add your own processor to this pipeline and see why the `$date` is not replaced properly:

```cs
  public class ReplaceVariables : ExpandInitialFieldValueProcessor
  {
    public override void Process(ExpandInitialFieldValueArgs args)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, "args");
      MasterVariablesReplacer variablesReplacer = Factory.GetMasterVariablesReplacer();
      string text = args.SourceField.Value;
      if (variablesReplacer == null)
        args.Result = text;
      else
        args.Result = variablesReplacer.Replace(text, args.TargetItem);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yeah .. I am using $date as a token in standard value. Which should ideally be replaced with the current date. But this is always taking the date as 1/1/0001

Comment: Just to confirm, you first set $date token in standard values and then you created a new item using this template and date was set to date time.min after that?

Comment: Yes . That's right. I am creating a new item after I set the token in standard values.

Comment: This is a known bug in Sitecore 8 . I want to use $date without any custom  implementation. According to Sitecore support, they have registered the bug and as a workaround suggested that we use the tokens ( $date, $now etc ) by checking the Raw values check box under view tab ). Thanks All for the suggestions :)